# ActionContext.getContext().getSession() returns null

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am using SessionAware in struts2 but when I am getting the value of session it returns null. my action class and methods are-

```
public class CustomLocation extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{
private Map<String, Object> sessionMap;

public String prepareEditCustomLocationForm()throws Exception{
    //----some code here------//
    sessionMap.put("LocEditId", id);
    return SUCCESS;
}


public String editCustomLocation() throws Exception{
Map session = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().getSession(); // it returns null
int id=(Integer)session.get("LocEditId");
//----------some code----------//
retutn SUCCESS;
}


@Override
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> map) {
this.sessionMap = map;    
}

}
```

Comment: check sessioMap have getter and setter method.

Comment: If you are using `SessionAware`, why you are trying to get session from `ActionContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to obtain a session map to the action.

1. Implement `SessionAware`. By default the session map is populated on action call. This is a preferable way.
2. Get a session map from the action context. This way you should make sure the request is handled by the struts2 filter.

Try

```
public String editCustomLocation() throws Exception{
  int id=(Integer)sessionMap.get("LocEditId");
  //----------some code----------//
  retutn SUCCESS;
}
```