# Null pointer exception (implementing session on Struts2)

Tags: java, session, struts2

I followed many examples on how to use `SessionAware` in a Struts 2 project and I always get a `NullPointerException` when I want to put data in the session. Why?

```
public class UserService extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

private Map<String,Object> sessionmap;

@Override  
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> sessionmap) {  
    this.sessionmap = sessionmap;
}

public String execute() {
    sessionmap.put("id", iduser);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No, the problem is that the session doesn't want to make put

Comment: The problem is that the sessionmap is null. You can't call a method on a object that is null. In short, it means that the setter was never called. Put a breakpoint in your code and you'll see.

Comment: What does your interceptor stack look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24585967/573032

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Wesley said the problem is that session map is null thats why you get null pointer eception, the solution is to add this `this.sessionmap = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();` before the `put` in the `execute` method
like this

```
public String execute(){
        this.sessionmap = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        sessionmap.put("id", iduser);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't the answer. This is *an* answer, but is almost always the wrong one--the reason `SessionAware` exists is to help S2 actions be as POJO-like as possible, which is an aid in testing. Reaching into `ActionContext` directly breaks that abstraction and makes testing (in particular) more difficult than necessary.